# How to bubble sort a arraylist in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, bubble-sort

How to bubble sort a arraylist in java?
i want to bubble sort an arraylist. or is there a better way to sort an arraylist or list.

Comment: Bubblesort is a slow algorithm... but it's ok for learning purposes :)

Comment: Why not go straight to [bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort)? Propably useful for learning, too ;)

Answer (score 2):

> is there a better way to sort an arraylist or list.

Yes: use the sorting that is built into the standard library.

For example, http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29

Answer (score 0):

To sort an ArrayList I used the Collections.sort(), included the in the ArrayList class.
eg.

```
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

To sort it I would say,

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

and this would sort the `ArrayList`